# OpenAM Password Policy priority

Tags: openam, password-policy

We use OpenAM to manage users that have access to multiple applications. Access to all is controlled using SSO through OpenAM. 
Some of the applications need to have specific (minimum) password policies. When a user has access to more than one application for which there is a defined unique policy then the applied policy for the user password should be the most stringent.

How do we enforce this? In effect can we define a priority order for password policies?

Cheers
Daryl

Comment: the authentication is centralized and authorization is different from authentication.
If a user has already authenticated (because this is SSO) and is requesting a resource which would require a stricter password policy ... what should happen?

OpenAM mostly is not responsible for the password policy (I guess you are referring to an LDAP Directory Server being used).

In the directory server however only ONE password policy can be applied for a given DN (as far as I know).

Comment: Even if you use 'scoped password policies' you have to change the criteria , which determines what password policy should apply, BEFORE the user authenticates.

So it's kind of a chicken-egg issue.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I explained it very well.  We currently have users that have more than one applicable password policy. So here is the scenario.